# python regex pattern doesn't match in string even matching in testers (re-try, regex coach, http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com)

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I've build a regex pattern to my target: a string with data obtained from a CSV file. I'm an almost completely newbie in programming, but i'm really stuck in this step, and i've tried hard to fix the problem, as regular expressions are the (i think...) best choice from my problem, that is a search in data from CSV files with some differences betwen them but with a pattern that obeys a formal protocol (MIAME files, from the bioinformatics field). This is my code

```
import re
    ficheiro=open(raw_input('write the name of the file (formato CSV):'), 'r')
    lista_file=ficheiro.readlines()
    str_file=str(lista_file)
    list_spr=[]
    value_spr=[]
    for a in str_file:
        regex_spr = re.search(r"(spr[0-9]{4})[^\t.]*\t([0-9.]+)", a, re.I|re.M)
        print regex_spr.group()
        list_spr +=regex_spr.group(1)
        value_spr +=regex_spr.group(2)
```

but the result is always something with `'NoneType'`, like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EDPython27\test\put_words_in_dict.py", line 112, in <module>
    print regex_spr.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Next is some of the range of str_file that i used to test the pattern:

```
('Reporter Identifier\tVALUE\n', 'spr0320060100000320\t4.784064198\n', 'spr0963060100000963\t3.646246197\n', 'spr1586060100001584\t5.755770215\n', 'spr1102060100001101\t5.794439261\n', 'spr1727060100001725\t6.452100774\n', 'spr0552060100000552\t6.816527711\n', 'spr0807060100000807\t3.185267941\n', 'spr0322060100000322\t5.889496662\n', 'spr0971060100000971\t3.112604228\n', 'spr0490060100000490\t6.608164616\n', 'spr0471060100000471\t6.807244139\n', 'spr0321060100000321\t5.331036948\n', 'spr1070060100001069\t6.408937689\n', 'spr1585060100001583\t6.157044216\n', 'spr1189060100001188\t3.481847857\n', 'spr1191060100001190\t3.523784616\n', 'spr1081060100001080\t6.708517655\n', 'spr1071060100001070\t7.092586967\n', 'spr1101060100001100\t6.294650154\n', 'spr0561060100000561\t7.52495517\n', 'spr0802060100000802\t8.299020685\n', 'spr1195060100001194\t6.143485258\n', 'spr0470060100000470\t5.869271803\n', 'spr1944060100001941\t7.060765363\n', 'spr0968060100000968\t6.276636704\n', 'spr1072060100001071\t7.267895537\n', 'spr0972060100000972\t5.535911422\n', 'spr1821060100001819\t7.660640949\n', 'spr0316060100000316\t6.399083059\n', 'spr0129060100000129\t6.693897057\n', 'spr0966060100000966\t6.208969299\n', 'spr0323060100000323\t6.230187159\n', 'spr1466060100001465\t7.609506586\n', 'spr0964060100000964\t6.286528191\n', 'spr1665060100001663\t5.597969101\n', 'spr0969060100000969\t5.122425278\n', 'spr1394060100001393\t7.310099682\n', 'spr0683060100000683\t7.397780719\n', 'spr1649060100001647\t6.121430945\n', 'spr0536060100000536\t7.936838283\n', 'spr1020060100001020\t7.339227818\n', 'spr0682060100000682\t7.435907739\n', 'spr0606060100000606\t6.251491879\n', 'spr0491060100000491\t5.400560984\n', 'spr0939060100000939\t6.928170725\n', 'spr1492060100001491\t7.451461913\n', 'spr0965060100000965\t5.610110186\n', 'spr1188060100001187\t3.384989187\n', 'spr1296060100001295\t5.927021756\n')
```

To all advisers i thank in advance.

Comment: `re.search` returns `None` when a match is not found.

Comment: Yes, i know that. But my problem is just don't know why, and mainly WHEN is the error in the regex expression, because it works in the testers. Also please ignore the two last lines. i don't even know if they are syntactically correct

Answer (score 1):

From the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) on `re.search()`:

> Scan through string looking for a location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return **None** if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern

Hence the workaround here will be to check whether `regex_spr`  is `None` or not.

```
for a in str_file:
    regex_spr = re.search(r"(spr[0-9]{4})[^\t.]*\t([0-9.]+)", a, re.I|re.M)
    if regex_spr is not None:
        print regex_spr.group()
        list_spr +=regex_spr.group(1)
        value_spr +=regex_spr.group(2)
    else:
         #do something else
```